# Passing a superclass object as a parameter to a method with a subclass parameter

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

In the below code 'NPC' and 'Settlement' are both subclasses of the superclass 'Feature' (I have removed irrelevant parts of the generateNewRelationships() method)

```
public ArrayList<Relationship> generateNewRelationships(ArrayList<Feature> features) {
    for(Feature feature: features) {
        ArrayList<Predicate> possiblePredicates = filterPredicates(feature, subjectPredicates);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Predicate> filterPredicates(NPC npc, ArrayList<Predicate> npcPredicates) {
    // Does NPC filter
}

private ArrayList<Predicate> filterPredicates(Settlement settlement, ArrayList<Predicate> settlementPredicates) {
    // Does Settlement filter
}
```

Now the call of the filterPredicates method doesn't work as there is no method that takes 'Feature' as a parameter type. Is there a way to cast the 'feature' variable so that it is casted as the subtype that it is actually referencing, so that the correct method is used?

I want to avoid manually writing out a if/else or switch statement, as in future there will be more subclasses of Feature.

There will never be an instance of a 'Feature', only instances of its subclasses, so the ArrayList features will only ever contain NPCs or Settlements.

(This is a repost of my question as it was closed saying PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super) was the solution, but that is about passing collections as parameters. My question is asking about how to write the call to 'filterPredicates(feature, subjectPredicates)' where an individual object 'feature' will alternate between Feature subtypes 'NPC' and 'Settlement' within the for loop, so that 'feature' is cast as an NPC or a Settlement, depending on what subtype 'feature' actually holds at that time.)

Comment: The way question is posted right now, it might receive downvotes and eventually close.  To prevent that, please post a minimal compilable and reproducible code here. Better format your question and ask "exactly" whats not working for you.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tintin mentioned, without more example code & detail it is difficult to give a really good answer.

But you have one specific question which can be answered: **"Is there a way to cast the 'feature' variable so that it is casted as the subtype that it is actually referencing, so that the correct method is used?"**

If you want to cast `Feature` to a subtype, you'll need to first identify which subtype you want to cast to. If there are many possible subtypes, you would need to check which one it is using `instanceof`. But you mentioned you don't want to do this.

So in order to avoid the `instanceof` checking, one option is to work with `Feature` instead of the subclasses. This will work because converting from subclass (`NPC` or `Settlement`) to superclass (`Feature`) does not require you to write any explicit checking code.

One possible option here is to simply update the `Feature` interface so it can be used for what you want to do. You can add a function to `Feature` called `matchesPredicate` and implement it differently for `NPC` and `Settlement`. Then `filterPredicates` can change to something like this:

```
// matchesPredicate in the Feature interface: "boolean matchesPredicate(Predicate p);"

private ArrayList<Predicate> filterPredicates(Feature feature, ArrayList<Predicate> predicates) {
   ArrayList<Predicate> result = new ArrayList();

   for (Predicate p : predicates) {
       if (feature.matchesPredicate(p)) {
           result.add(p);
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```

(Note: At the time of this answer you didn't write what the `filterPredicates` function body does so I am guessing a bit here with that code.)